# How to access public variables, and getting return values in smart contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Say I have a smart contract such as:

```
contact Rabbit {
    string public name;

    function setName(string n) returns (bool) {
        name = n;
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of `name` after having set it? I'm using Truffle. I've tried (where `rabbit` is a handle of `Rabbit`:

```
rabbit.name();
```

This just returns `''`.

Also, how can I get the return value? If I execute `setName` I just see the transaction, not the return value. I read somewhere I can use `call()`, such as: `rabbit.setName.call("barry")`, though it wont save the transaction so it needs ot be call again, without `call()`. Have I got this wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insertion can be done using `sendTransaction` function.

```
 Rabbit.deployed().then(function(contract) {contract.createProperty("Hello",{from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(v) {console.log(v)})})
```

You can use `call` method to get the value of public variable.Try the below command in truffle console.

```
 Rabbit.deployed().then(function(contract)  {contract.name.call().then(function(v) {console.log(v)})})
```